# What are the performance characteristics of 'is' reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

It's [shown](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx) that 'as' casting is much faster than prefix casting, but what about 'is' reflection?  How bad is it?  As you can imagine, searching for 'is' on Google isn't terribly effective.

Comment: I realize that date isn't the only determining factor in closing duplicate questions, but my question was posted and answered and upvoted all before the other question was posted.  _It_ is the duplicate, not this one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. The **classic cast**: `Foo foo = (Foo)bar`
2. The **`as` cast operator**: `Foo foo = bar as Foo`
3. The **`is` test**: `bool is = bar is Foo`

---

1. The **classic cast** needs to check if `bar` can be safely cast to `Foo` (quick), and then actually do it (slower), or throw an exception (really slow).
2. The **`as` operator** needs to check if `bar` can be cast, then do the cast, or if it cannot be safely cast, then it just returns `null`.
3. The **`is` operator** just checks if `bar` can be cast to Foo, and return a `boolean`.

The **`is`** test is quick, because it only does the first part of a full casting operation. The **`as`** operator is quicker than a classic cast because doesn't throw an exception if the cast fails (which makes it good for situations where you legitimately expect that the cast might fail).

If you just need to know if the variable `bar`is a `Foo` then use the **`is`** operator, **BUT**, if you're going to test if `bar` is a `Foo`, and if so, **then cast it**, then you should use the **`as`** operator.

Essentially every cast needs to do the equivalent of an `is` check internally to begin with, in order to ensure that the cast is valid. So if you do an `is` check followed by a full cast (either an `as` cast, or with the classic cast operator) you are effectively doing the `is` check twice, which is a slight extra overhead.

Comment: The check is the slowest, the cast is very fast on reference types, because it just returns the reference.

Answer (score 8):

The way I learned it is that this:

```
if (obj is Foo) {
  Foo f = (Foo)obj;
  f.doSomething();
}
```

is slower than this:

```
Foo f = obj as Foo;
if (f != null) {
  f.doSomething();
}
```

Is it slow enough to matter? Probably not, but it's such a simple thing to pay attention for, that you might as well do it.

Answer (score 6):

"is" is basically equivalent to the "isinst" IL operator -- which that article describes as fast.

Answer (score 2):

It should be quick enough to not matter. If you are checking the type of an object enough for it to make a noticeable impact on performance you need to rethink your design