# Which is good to use: Object.GetType() == typeof(Type) or Object is Type?

Tags: c#, performance, types

I want to know that which statement is useful from a *Performance Point of View* whether to use

```
Object.GetType() == typeof(Type)
```

or

```
Object is Type
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is?rq=1

Comment: It's important to understand these two are not equivalent and when dealing with inheritance or interfaces, one will return false and the other true. Bharadwaj's linked question demonstrates these differences.

Comment: You can have actually tested this by yourself.

Comment: @t3chb0t: tests can indeed give an indication, but as you can see, the answer also provides an explanation: there exist dedicated CIL instructions for `is` whereas the `.GetType() == ` is resolved by performing expensive function calls.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The second one:

```
Object is Type
```

Tested this 1'000'000'000 times with `string` versus `int` one gets:

```
//Release
00:00:18.1428040 //Object.GetType() == typeof(Type)
00:00:03.9791070 //Object is Type
//Debug
00:00:21.3545510 //Object.GetType() == typeof(Type)
00:00:06.2969510 //Object is Type
//Machine specs:
//Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
//6 GB RAM memory
//Ubuntu 14.04 (OS)
//Runtime: Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8
//Compiler: Mono dmcs
//Notes: ran these with some background processes, but the difference in time
//       is significant enough I guess.
```

> **Note**: There is a **strong semantic difference** between the two:
>
> - The equality `==` checks on type equality: in other words, if `A : B`
>     than the equality test will fail for `A.GetType() == typeof(B)`
>     whereas `A is B` will succeed.
> - If the object is `null`, it will throw a `System.NullReferenceException`. In the second case, it will return
>     `false`.

This is rather logic from a compiler point-of-view: in the first variant, you query the object for its type. In case that's not really optimized, you do a function call first, that call then says it must return a pointer to the type-table.

In the second case, you omit such calls: the compiler will specialize it by returning the type-code. And if the `Type` is known in advance, it can even work out a very fast test for it.

Note furthermore that for some trivial cases, `Object is Type` can be optimized: for instance because the compiler can already derive that `Object` can't/is always of type `Type`.

**More advanced**

One can also analyze the CIL virtual machine source code, for the first variant, this is:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
IL_0006: ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_000b: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_0010: call bool [mscorlib]System.Type::op_Equality(class [mscorlib]System.Type, class [mscorlib]System.Type)
IL_0015: ret
```

For the second variant this is:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: isinst [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0006: ldnull
IL_0007: cgt.un
IL_0009: ret
```

(you can of course fill in other types). Now the `ldarg.0` and `ret` are simply by-products of using a method, so one can ignore them.

What one sees is that in the first variant, one calls the `GetType` method explicitly and then calls the `==` operator. Function calls are in general expensive. In the second variant, it checks immediately for `isinst`. The code requires less bytes and uses less expensive methods. Although performance of course depends on the implementation of the runtime environment, I think it's rather safe to say the second variant will nearly always beat the first one on performance.

A compiler could probably *specialize* the first variant such that it runs as efficient as the second, but the Mono C# compiler doesn't seem to do this. Probably none of the available C# compilers will.

Comment: I can not accept this answer within 4 min?

Comment: @AmolBavannavar: that's to give other users an opportunity to come up with a better answer. And for such question, that's very likely.

Comment: but the way you answered this question is very good. It is this which I want from this thread. Got it . Thanks a lot..

Comment: You've answered this under four minutes with test measurements? That's incredible ;-)

Comment: Nice answer, also "small semantic difference" is somewhat understatement - they check completely different things for derived classes/interfaces.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: modified, better?

Comment: Side note: maybe you should consider copying/merging into duplicate as there is no such point of view covered there yet.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: well the "duplicate" deals more with the "semantical difference" whereas this question is more towards performance. Personally I think this is a difference... If you insist, indeed the answers should be merged).

Comment: Fair - I've added comment linking to this one. ... deleting unrelated comments 30...29..

Comment: Doesn't this answer contradicts [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/184697/6474510) one, saying simply the opposite?