# If Control is Radiobutton or Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which changes Title depends on users selection. Then i want to create a properties for the control, either radiobutton or checkbox. They have same properties but i cant implement well.

```
 private void DeleteEdit()
      {
        Control[] EmployeesControl; //I think this is the problem, but i cant figure it out.

        if (Form_AddEmployee.Text.Contains("Edit"))
        {
            EmployeesControl = new RadioButton[numberOfEmployees];
        }
        else if (Form_AddEmployee.Text.Contains("Delete"))
        {
            EmployeesControl = new CheckBox[numberOfEmployees];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < EmployeesControl.Count(); i++)
        {
            EmployeesControl[i] = new EmployeesControl();
            InitializeControls(EmployeesControl[i]);
            EmployeesControl[i].Visible = true;
            panelEmployee.Controls.Add(EmployeesControl[i]);
            EmployeesControl[i].Text = stringTemp;
            EmployeesControl[i].Location = new Point(100, 100 * (i+1));
            EmployeesControl[i].Font = MyFont;
            EmployeesControl[i].CheckedChanged += EmployeesDeleteEditEmployees_CheckedChanged;
        }
    }
```

How can i make a variable if a certain control is a radiobutton or checkbox.

Comment: Hint: [`is` or `typeof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184681/is-vs-typeof).

Comment: You don't gain much by trying to do this with one block of code.  But... Get rid of the array, make it `For (int i = 0; i < numberOfEmployees; i++)` then do your If blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetType` to check, after you will change `EmployeesControl[i]` to CheckBox or RadioButton.

```
private void DeleteEdit()
{
    Control[] EmployeesControl; //I think this is the problem, but i cant figure it out.

    if (Form_AddEmployee.Text.Contains("Edit"))
        {
            EmployeesControl = new RadioButton[numberOfEmployees];
            for (int i = 0; i < EmployeesControl.Count(); i++)
            {
                EmployeesControl[i] = new RadioButton();
            }
        }
        else if (Form_AddEmployee.Text.Contains("Delete"))
        {
            EmployeesControl = new CheckBox[numberOfEmployees];
            for (int i = 0; i < EmployeesControl.Count(); i++)
            {
                EmployeesControl[i] = new CheckBox();
            }
        }
    ButtonBase b;
    CheckBox chk;
    RadioButton rdo;
    for (int i = 0; i < EmployeesControl.Count(); i++)
    {
        b = (ButtonBase)EmployeesControl[i];//You use b to set property
        if (EmployeesControl[i].GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
        {
            rdo = (RadioButton)EmployeesControl[i];

            //Your code
            //................
            rdo.CheckedChanged += EmployeesDeleteEditEmployees_CheckedChanged;                    
        }
        else
        {
            chk = (RadioButton)EmployeesControl[i];

            //Your code
            //...............
            chk.CheckedChanged += EmployeesDeleteEditEmployees_CheckedChanged;
        }

        //EmployeesControl[i] = new EmployeesControl();
        //InitializeControls(EmployeesControl[i]);
        //EmployeesControl[i].Visible = true;
        //panelEmployee.Controls.Add(EmployeesControl[i]);
        //EmployeesControl[i].Text = stringTemp;
        //EmployeesControl[i].Location = new Point(100, 100 * (i + 1));
        //EmployeesControl[i].Font = MyFont;
        //EmployeesControl[i].CheckedChanged += EmployeesDeleteEditEmployees_CheckedChanged;                      
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: its not working. if (EmployeesControl[i].GetType() == typeof(RadioButton)) is null

Comment: yes its working. but my problem is, the checkbox and radiobutton has similar properties. so its means i will copy and paste same code.

Comment: ButtonBase is base class of both RadioButton and CheckBox . You can use change RadioButton and CheckBox to ButtonBase. After you can set properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ButtonBase class to your perpouse.

Declare array of controls by ButtonBase, so common properties of CheckBox and RadioButton you can use without casting.

Properties of CheckBox or RadioButton you can access by

```
var a = EmployeesControl[i] as CheckBox;
if (a != null)
{
    //this is checkbox
    continue;
}
var b = EmployeesControl[i] as RadioButton;
if (b != null)
{
    //this is RadioButton
}
```