# Difference between casting and as?

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the difference between the following casts in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702234/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-casts-in-c)

In C#, is a there difference between casting an object or using the `as` keyword? Hopefully this code will illustrate what I mean...

```
String text = "Hello hello";
Object obj = text; 

String originalCast = ((String)obj).ToUpper();
String originalAs = (obj as String).ToUpper();
```

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702234/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-casts-in-c and many many others

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483/casting-newtype-vs-object-as-newtype

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) will never throw a [`InvalidCastException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception).  Instead, it returns null if the cast fails (which would give you a [`NullReferenceException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception) if `obj` in your example were not a `string`).

Comment: His example wouldn't give NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Blindy - yes it would. He's trying to do a ToUpper() on what could potentially be a null object.

Comment: Thanks, thought it might of been just shorthand!

Comment: @rein - I think Blindy meant that his example as provided will not cause a runtime error. `obj` is assigned to a string object in line 2.

Answer (score 23):

Other than `InvalidCastException` that's already mentioned...

`as` will not work if the target type is a value type (unless it's nullable):

```
obj as int // compile time error.
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know!

Using 'as' will return null if the 'cast' fails where casting will throw an exception if the cast fails.

Answer (score 5):

Using 'as' will not throw an exception if the obj is not a String.  Instead it'll return null.  Which in your case will still throw an exception since you're immediately referencing this null value.