# What is the difference between these two C# statements?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# “as” cast vs classic cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926677/c-sharp-as-cast-vs-classic-cast)

I've inherited some code and I see this Grid event handler.  I don't know if there's a difference between these two statements, I wouldn't think there is, but the fact that they are back to back in the code makes me wonder why do the same thing two ways (assuming they do the same thing).  Could someone explain the difference, if any?

```
            GridDataItem ParentItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

            GridDataItem NewRow = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
```

Comment: i thought so too, but that he did it that way threw me off. I'd never seen the first way but it appears to do the same thing.  I wonder why he did it

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926677/c-sharp-as-cast-vs-classic-cast.

Comment: This has been asked a million times in the past - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955250/c-sharp-difference-between-casting-and-as

Comment: you are correct, sir!  Thanks all, for the answers.  Appreciate the help bigtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception"

"Note that the as operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions. The as operator cannot perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions."

[Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

First one: ParentItem will be `null` if `e.Item` is not of the Type `GridDataItem`.

The second: It will throw an Exception, if `e.Item` is not of the type `GridDataItem`

Answer (score 2):

```
//This will perform a safe conversion.  Null will be retuirned if e.Item is not
//a GridDataItem
GridDataItem ParentItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

//This will throw an exception if e.Item is not a GridDataItem
GridDataItem NewRow = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
```

See FAQ:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-cast-syntax-and-using-the-code-as-code-operator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

These are two different ways to cast `e.Item` to a `GridDataItem`, depending on how you want the scenario where `e.Item` is not a `GridDataItem` to be handled.

**In the first case, using `as`:** you will always get a result, but if `e.Item` is not a `GridDataItem` that result will be `null`.

**In the second case, using an explicit cast:** if `e.Item` is not a `GridDataItem`, then your code will throw an `InvalidCastException` (which you can catch).

Answer (score 1):

The first line will ensure that ParentItem is null if typecasting is not possible. The second line will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Using "as" instead of the explicit cast will not throw an exception if the conversion fails, but instead return null.

Answer (score 0):

If e is a GridDataItem, no différences.
If not :
the "as" operator will return Null
the "impossible catch" will throw an exception

So the difference is "just" how you handle false situations.