# Difference between Object type casting (as / (int)) in C#

Tags: c#, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the following casts in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702234/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-casts-in-c)

While am working on C#, her am doing type casting at that point I got a doubt:-

> What is the difference between Object type casting for "as vs. (int)/(string)/... soon"?

### Example:

```
int a = (int) value;
```

VS.

```
int a = value as int;
```

---

```
string a = (string) value;
```

VS.

```
string a = value as string;
```

---

and soon...

Can any help explain this in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this link 

[Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr

Comment: May help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132445/direct-casting-vs-as-operator/132467#132467

Comment: Thanks all for the information provided.

Answer (score 3):

[From msdn:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> The as operator is used to perform certain types of conversions
>   between compatible reference or nullable types.
>
> Remarks:
>
> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.
>   Consider the following expression:
>
> ```
> expression as type
> ```
>
> It is equivalent to the following expression except that expression is
>   evaluated only one time.
>
> ```
> expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
> ```
>
> Note that the as operator only performs conversions to reference or
>   nullable types, and boxing conversions. The as operator cannot perform
>   other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should
>   instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use as for non-nullable value type, you can only use as for nullable one only. What I mean is that the below line will give you a build error/

```
int a = value as int;
```

Any way, the as returns null if the cast is not valid. We usually use it.

```
Class1 c1 = value as Class1;
if (c1 != null)
{
    //do your logic.
}
```

Comment: You can't use `as` for a *non-nullable* value type. You can use it for a nullable one, e.g. `int? y = x as int?;`

Comment: I was *contradicting* you. Your first sentence is incorrect, in the way indicated by my comment.

Comment: Better, although still not as clear as it might be. (My comment was *in the context* of your original sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

The major difference between prefix- and as-casting is what happens when the cast fails. Imagine, for instance, that g is really an instance of AnotherSpecificType, which is not a subclass of SpecificType. In this case, the prefix-cast throws an exception — however, the as-cast returns null when the cast fails, letting the execution of the program barrel on.

Look at this article:

https://sites.google.com/site/gmamaladze/projects/short-articles/prefix-casting-versus-as-casting-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Using the as operator differs from a cast in C# in three important ways:

- It returns null when the variable you are trying to convert is not of the requested type or in it's inheritance chain, instead of throwing an exception.
- It can only be applied to reference type variables converting to reference types.
- Using as will not perform user-defined conversions, such as implicit or explicit conversion operators, which casting syntax will do.

Comment: As noted in another comment, it can also be applied to nullable value types.

Answer (score 0):

If you try casting as `as` on a `value` type, for example `int a = value as int;`, you will get an `InvalidCastException`. Value types must be casted as `(int) intValue`.

If you are considering any `reference` type. You may use `as` where failed on casting will return `null`. You may use direct casting like `(string) value`, here will get an `exception` if the casting fails.