# What is the difference between string url = (string)data AND string url = data as string;

Tags: c#, string, casting

What is the difference between

string url = (string)data
AND
string url = data as string;

Which is a better way ?

Comment: Repost of many other questions I mean duplicate : [What is the difference between the following casts in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702234/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-casts-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first construct will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the cast fails, whereas the `as` operator will return null if the `data` variable is not a string.

> Which is a better way ?

It will depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `as` as an **attempt** to cast the object to a specific type. If it fails, the resulting variable will hold `null`. Direct casting on the other hand is a `1 way ticket` cast, if it fails an exception will be thrown.

Essentially, they do the exact same thing when the object can be cast to the specific type, but in the event that your cast is invalid, one will throw an exception and the other will "fail gracefully".

Which one you use really depends on the scenario. If your variable is an integral part of the code (i.e, if there's no point in continuing with the proceeding code if the cast fails), just use a direct cast and handle the exception. However, there are cases where not throwing an exception and handling the null value is extremely useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

as keyword is defensive cast, does not throw exception when there is one in casting