# How does the " is " operator work internally

Tags: .net

I want to compare the type of an object to a type to see if they are the same.  I do not have the object, just the type of the object.

I can do   `type1 == type2`  and get general equality

I can have a recursive loop where I repeat the above step for `type1.BaseType` until the BaseType is null.

I can do   `type1.GetInterface( type2.FullName ) != null`  to check if type2 is an interface of type1

If I put it all together, I get

```
if ( type2.IsInterface )
  return type1.GetInterface( type2.FullName ) != null;

while ( type1 != null ) {
  if ( type1 == type2 )
    return true;

  type1 = type1.BaseType;
}
return false;
```

Is that all the `is` keyword is.  I cannot find the right keyword to plug into the Reflector search to find the function and a google search on "is" was not really helpful

Comment: It depends on what the meaning of the word 'is' is

Comment: +1 interesting.  However, I would assume the "is" keyword is implemented natively in the runtime and does not use reflection.

Comment: I never thought I'd see a relevant Bill Clinton quote on SO.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134004/c-is-operator-is-that-reflection

Comment: Are there the C++ type_info and typeid() underlying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) (§14.9.10 of [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)) generally uses [isinst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx), but it doesn't need to if the compile-time type is compatible via certain conversions.

A equivalent (in reverse) with a Type object is [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).  All of these are true:

```
"foo" is String;
"foo" is object;

typeof(String).IsAssignableFrom("foo".GetType());
typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom("foo".GetType());
```

Comment: Be careful, an `isinst` instruction isn't always generated.  The C# compiler can tell when you're being dumb and will generate comparisons with null instead of `isinsts`.